# Sintaxe .cshtml - DevExpress

Tags: c#, html, devexpress

Na página *.aspx*, tenho um *ASPxRichEdit* e no topo do código coloco:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit" TagPrefix="dx" %>
```

Funciona normal. O componente aparece na tela.

Agora preciso colocar o mesmo componente numa página *.cshtml*, porém com o código acima não funcionou. Como seria a sintaxe pra *.cshtml*? Na documentação da DevExpress, só aparece pra *.aspx*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, leia a documentação do componente que está implementando.

Na sua view:

```
 @Html.Partial("RichEditPartial")
```

Crie a Partial View  view para o componente:

```
  @Html.DevExpress().RichEdit(settings => {
        settings.Name = "RichEdit";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "RichEditPartial" };
        }).Open(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Documents/Overview.rtf")).GetHtml()
```

E adicione a Action em sua Controller:

```
public ActionResult RichEditPartial(){
    return PartialView("RichEditPartial");
}
```

**Fonte:**

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/114046/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Rich-Text-Editor/Overview/Overview-Rich-Text-Editor

Comment: @lucaswmolin, conseguiu?

Comment: Não. Apareceu alguns erros que estou resolvendo, mas quando resolvo um aparece outro...

Comment: Feito! Consegui entender melhor com este vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdO07KuPGqM